# How to enable Cognito "Attribute verification and user account confirmation" in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-aws-modules

This is the terraform script that I use to create Cognito user pool:

```
resource "aws_cognito_user_pool" "user_pool" {
  name = "${var.app_name}-user-pool"

  username_attributes = ["email"]

  verification_message_template {
    default_email_option = "CONFIRM_WITH_CODE"
    email_subject        = "Account Confirmation"
    email_message        = "Your confirmation code is {####}"
  }
}

resource "aws_cognito_user_pool_client" "client" {
  name = "${var.app_name}-cognito-client"

  user_pool_id                  = aws_cognito_user_pool.user_pool.id
  generate_secret               = false
  refresh_token_validity        = 90
  prevent_user_existence_errors = "ENABLED"
  explicit_auth_flows = [
    "ALLOW_REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH",
    "ALLOW_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH",
    "ALLOW_ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH",
    "ALLOW_CUSTOM_AUTH",
    "ALLOW_USER_SRP_AUTH"
  ]

}

resource "aws_cognito_user_pool_domain" "cognito-domain" {
  domain       = "${var.app_name}userpooldomain"
  user_pool_id = aws_cognito_user_pool.user_pool.id
}
```

But then I manually added the attribute verification and user account confirmation, like in the image. What I need is to add what's in the picture to my terraform script
[image]

I was reading the documentation but I haven't logo it yet

Comment: I think you are looking for [auto_verified_attributes](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cognito_user_pool#auto_verified_attributes) and [user_attribute_update_settings](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cognito_user_pool#user_attribute_update_settings) arguments.